# How do you store integer into a variable and computeAvg in java?

Tags: java, variables, math

I am trying to write  a Java program that:

- In the main method, prompt the user for an integer number.
- Store the number in a variable called `inputNum`.
- Pass the `inputNum` to a method called `computeAvg`.
- In `computeAvg`, prompt the user to input double values as many times as `inputNum`. `computeAvg` method should calculate and return the average of real numbers that user entered.
- Print the result in your main method.

This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a integer? ");
    int x;
    x = keyboard.nextInt();
    int inputnum=x;
    computeAvg();
}

public static void computeAvg() {
    System.out.println(inputnum);
    System.out.println("Enter double values as inputnum ");
    int y;
    y=keyboard.nextInt();
}    
}
```

Comment: if you want a double, use `double y = keyboard.nextDouble();`

Comment: I was just thinking that, thanks for pointint that out.

Comment: I'am agree with Thilo

Comment: if x is the number of times a user needs to input a number, then you should be using a `loop` on your `computeAvg` method.

Comment: [Passing Information to a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) and [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: thanks MadProgrammer that helped

Comment: Why is this question being down voted. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Keep hold of this tutorial links, they are gold. While not a down voter, the question is a little vague about the actual problem you're having and what you have tried to fix it, although you have provided an attempt, which is always considered a plus

Comment: Thanks for the help MadProgrammer.

Comment: While homework questions tend to be downvote magnets I suspect a big reason you've getting voted down is because the questions title is a bit misleading.  It's not to late to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several changes to be done in your code:

```
  static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
          public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println("Please enter a integer? ");
       int x;
       x = keyboard.nextInt();
       int inputnum=x;
              System.out.println("The average is"+computeAvg(inputnum));

        }
         public static double computeAvg(int y)
         {
             double[] arr = new double[y];
       System.out.println(y);
             for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                 System.out.println("Enter double values ");
                 arr[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
             }
             double sum = 0;
             for(double a:arr){
                 sum +=a;
             }
             System.out.println(sum);
             double average = sum/arr.length;
             return average;
       }
```

First one is that the value you first taken as the user input must be passed to the method. Here I done it in `computeAvg(inputnum)` And expect this method to return a double value.

Second one is You should declare the method to return a value `void` means no return. change it  to `double`

`public static double computeAvg(int y)`

take the parameter from the main method (value you taken from the user.)

If you need to store multiple values better solutions is array.(There are many methods bust for a beginner stick to arrays) crate a double array to take multiple double values.

`double[] arr = new double[y];`

next loop your code for the number of times the user input and take the double values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                     System.out.println("Enter double values ");
                     arr[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
                 }
```

next create a double value `sum` and get the addition and the divide it to get the average (another double value).

```
for(double a:arr){
                     sum +=a;
                 }
```

Finally return the average to the main method where it prints.

I used `static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` because I used the same scanner in both methods.

Feel free to ask any question regarding the code.

Comment: You are amazing thanks for taking your time to explain it. I'm starting to get this. THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!!

Comment: Since you are a beginner. explore more and don't give up easily on questions. Good luck in the future.

Comment: How do I mark it as correct and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the comments in the code are self explanatory for what the problem is asking and how the code works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer? ");
    // here you are asking for the number of double numbers that will be
    // entered
    int inputnum = keyboard.nextInt(); // asking for the int input (varibale
                                        // is stored in inputnum)
    System.out.println("Average for all " + inputnum + " numbers is: "
            + computeAvg(inputnum));

}

public static double computeAvg(int inputnum) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double eachInput = 0.0;
    double sumInputs = 0.0;
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= inputnum; counter++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a double as input #" + counter
                + ": ");
        eachInput = keyboard.nextDouble(); // asking for double input
        sumInputs += eachInput; // adding up each input

    }
    // calculating and returning average
    return sumInputs / (double) inputnum;
}
```

Comment: FYI: @A_N_Y_R handles the scanner variable efficiently.